# Is a Schengen visa valid after marriage (new last name)

Tags: schengen

My spouse holds a Schengen visa, which is valid until the end of the year. She got my last name in addition to hers after we married. Is her Schengen visa still valid?

Comment: What does this have to do with expatriates? As asked, it appears to belong on [Travel.SE].